# How does setTimeout async timer work if we set a certain time?

Tags: javascript

Can you tell me who was the youtuber coding teacher maybe Net Ninja or Fireship who has taught that in this async setTimeout, it only promises to run it in a minimum time of 1 sec not less but it can be running in more than 1 sec(for example: 1015 milisec, or 1200 milsec)? What if we put something in the method that clearly needs more time than 1 sec?

```
setTimeout(() => {
console.log("Delayed for 1 second.");
}, "1000")
```

Comment: You can put whatever number of milliseconds in there. Not limited to 1000. You should however add it as a number (`1000`) and not string (`"1000"`)

Comment: do you prefer an accusation with or without proof?

Comment: Your question starts by asking for the name of a YouTuber, and then meanders off into a misunderstanding about `setTimeout`. What exactly is it you want to know?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve misunderstood.

The function you pass to `setTimeout` will not be called before the time specified has passed.

The time specified has absolutely nothing to do with how long that function takes to run after it is called.

If the main event loop is busy running other functions, then that will delay the time before the passed function is called.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("This has a timeout of 1 second.");
}, 1000);

const now = new Date();
const ten_seconds_in_ms = 10 * 1000;
const ten_seconds_hence = new Date(now.getTime() + ten_seconds_in_ms);

console.log("Now we start a while loop that lasts 10 seconds");

while (new Date() < ten_seconds_hence) {
  // Do nothing except block for 10 seconds
}

console.log("The while loop is over, so the main event loop is about to become free to look at the queue of tasks");
```

```html
Note that the logs in this should render OK in your browser developer tools, but will block repainting of the DOM so the embedded logs in the SO viewport will all be delayed by the while loop.
```

Comment: Do i see that in this case, the setTimeout run will be 10 sec not 1sec as set in there?